# Restricting user to input special-characters using Angular

Tags: html, angular, npm

User is allowed to enter all the alphabets and numbers but when the special-characters are entered then it shouldn't be entered in the the text box.

I tried doing this using (ng-pattern-restrict) but it's not working as expected, I think it might be possible that it needs to be imported in 
app-module.ts but not working.

`HTML FILE`

Comment: it is an AngularJS package

Comment: I think rather than restricting user from entering special chars , won't it be good to let them type but invalidate the field & form ?? From user experience perspective, its better rather than disabling `keypress` events . Disabling special chars key press events might force the user to think that "my keyboard has broken keys"

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur it's not duplicate of that query,@Shashankvivek what I'm asking is that I don't want user to let key press and input in the text area instead of showing some error or warning to him.

Answer (score 0):

@Shashank has a valid point of view. What you want to do is disable the entry of special characters from the backend, as well as render the field invalid from the frontend. A hacker knowing what they're doing would easily manipulate the HTTP Request itself rather than the field, making it pretty vulnerable.

However, if you insist on your solution, I would recommend using RegEx. This [sample expression](https://www.regextester.com/96569) might come in handy. That way, whenever the input field detects one of these special characters, it would replace that character with a `''`

Comment: BTW Thanks Chris for a good suggestion, I really appreciate your approach towards my query. :)